# Automatic (keyless) styles not applied when in a MergedDictionaries in another assembly

Tags: .net, wpf

I moved the styles and templates xaml files form my application (.exe) project to a library project (.dll) because I want to use them in multiple applications.

In App.xaml I have:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApplication.Common;component/Resources/All.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

In All.xaml (in the Common assembly) :

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Templates.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Converters.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

With this code keyless styles in Styles.xaml aren't applied.

Instead, if I reference them directly in App.xaml, it works :

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApplication.Common;component/Resources/Styles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApplication.Common;component/Resources/Templates.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApplication.Common;component/Resources/Converters.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Can anyone explain why it happens ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an artifact of the implementation of the resource dictionary.  In your EXE, the relative references to the other dictionaries are not being found after All.xaml is merged into your App.xaml.  If you instead specify fully qualified (absolute) pack URIs for them, your application will then be able to find them.

So, in All.xaml replace this:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Templates.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Converters.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

With this:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApplication.Common;component/Resources/Styles.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApplication.Common;component/Resources/Templates.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApplication.Common;component/Resources/Converters.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```